# What’s the difference between &#10; and &NewLine;?

Tags: html

Apart from readability, what is the difference between the HTML codes `&#10;`and `&NewLine;`?

Comment: Nothing; one is the number code, the other is the entity code respectively. There is no difference other than readability in HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ASCII Code `&#10;`
>
> HTML Entity `&NewLine;`
>
> Hexadecimal value `&#x0000A;`
>
> These are all referring to the same thing but are represented in different ways. They all translate to Unicode `U+0000A LINE FEED (LF)`
>
> **Example:**
>
> The number `2` can be represented using `1+1`. It can also be represented using `|sqrt(4)|`. The result is the same, but using different syntaxes we can achieve the same result in different ways.

References:

https://theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/line-feed-ascii-code-10.html

https://www.quackit.com/character_sets/unicode/co_controls_and_basic_latin_unicode_character_codes.cfm

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_symbols.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ascii.asp